# Primefaces custom selectOneRadio, doesn't propagate to backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, radio-button

I'm currently having a problem with the `<p:radioButton>` and `<p:selectOneRadio>`. I'm trying to make a form with three radio buttons with some boxes next to them, this works and the "radio-mechanism" in the buttons work so that only one can be selected at once. However the selected radio button is not propagated to the backend. I've tried putting a `<p:ajax>` in the `<p:selectOneRadio>` to make it trigger some sort of call to the backing bean but with no success. I have looked at the following primefaces example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" layout="custom" value="advancedSettingsBean.radioValue">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" />
    <p:ajax />
</p:selectOneRadio>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <p:radioButton id="CheckboxValidTimeCurrent" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0">
        </p:radioButton>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{messages.search_advanced_validtimecurren}" /> 
        <br />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <p:radioButton id="CheckboxvValidTimeDate" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1">
        </p:radioButton>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{messages.search_advanced_validtimedate}" />
        <br /> 
        <p:calendar id="singledate" value="#{advancedSettingsBean.singleSearchDate}"
            datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" direction="smart" jointPoint="auto"
            inputStyle="width:80px" style="width: 200px">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" timeZone="UTC" />
        </p:calendar> Z 
        <br /> 
        <p:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false"
           id="singledateError" for="singledate" />
        <br />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <p:radioButton id="CheckboxvValidTimeSpan" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2">
        </p:radioButton>
    </td>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the value of selectoneradio in a el expression:

```
value="#{advancedSettingsBean.radioValue}"
```

Comment: #FML.. how could I miss that.. but thank you for pointing it out.. sometimes all you need is someone that hasn't been staring at it!

Comment: Nevermind, we all coding and concentrating so much, at such times, giving a break and going outside for a while is the best I guess.